# Jenkins - git issue

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, dockerfile

Trying to build docker image from docker file and pushing it to docker hub.
using the following script
[image]

getting the following error. Exactly what's missing here unable to figure it out.
[image]

Had to get a successful run but it's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the `git` ID you're specifying in `git credentialsID: 'git'` was not configured.

Make sure that the `git` ID credentials are specified in:

[image]